# Rails: Have I over-engineered this quiz and results page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Recently I've been trying to get a quiz page directing to a results page (and, with thanks to StanBoyet, I think I've finally managed it).

I have a User model and controller, and log in (using Devise) is all working fine. I have a QuizAnswers model and controller and all the tables present on the database. I also have a `ResultsController`.

Here is my `routes.rb` (note the resources):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

  get "elearning" => "home#elearning"
  get "howitworks" => "home#howitworks"
  get "leadershipstyles" => "home#leadershipstyles" 
  get "whattypeofleader" => "quizzes#new"
  get "showmetheskills" => "home#showmetheskills"
  get "safeguarding" => "home#safeguarding"
  get "toolsforthejob" => "home#toolsforthejob"
  get "whatnext" => "home#whatnext"
  get "congratulations" => "home#congratulations"
  get "teamwork" => "home#teamwork"
  get "facilitation" => "home#facilitation"
  get "planning" => "home#planning"
  get "communication" => "home#communication"

  resources :quizzes
  resources :results
  resources :quiz_answers

  resources :users do
    resources :posts  
  end
end
```

In my quiz form, I pass `form_for @quiz_answers` (made accessible by the `QuizAnswers#new` action):

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @quiz_answer = current_user.quiz_answers.build
end
```

(I have also tried, as an alternative, `@quiz_answer = QuizAnswer.new`)

When I click submit, the `QuizAnswers#create` action is triggered, which looks like this:

```
def create 
  redirect_to results_path
end
```

Which (rake routes tells me) points to `results#index` (`ResultsController#index` action) which I have set up like this:

```
def index
  # in order to access all the results in our view...
  @results = QuizAnswer.find(current_user.id)
end
```

When I click submit though, I'm getting the error:

Couldn't find QuizAnswer with 'id'=35

**I have two questions:**

How do I set up my new QuizAnswers with a reference to the id of the current_user? (QuizAnswers has a user_id attribute, as well as the usual id attribute).

Secondly, is this all horribly over-engineered or is this just 'the Rails way'? (If I'm doing it wrong, feel free to explain how I should do it 'right').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is very strange:

```
@results = QuizAnswer.find(current_user.id)
```

You need to change it to

```
@results = QuizAnswer.where(user_id: current_user.id)
#or
@results = current_user.quiz_answers
```

Comment: OK. The first one throws a 'can't cast Hash to integer' error at that line. The second option doesn't throw an error; I'll have to see how to access the QuizAnswer attributes from there. BTW - why are symbols sometimes typed with a colon at the END? That doesn't seem to be least surprising...

Comment: 1. Fixed 2. They can be typed with a colon at the end only in hashes. `find(user_id: current_user.id)` is equal to `find({ user_id: current_user.id })` what is equal to `find({ :user_id => current_user.id }).

Comment: OK. That multiple syntax seems to introduce ambiguity. Slightly pointless and frustrating. But thanks, again!